# What type of computer graphics is windows gdi for?

Tags: graphics, gdi

Windows GDI routines like MoveTo(), LineTo(). What type of computer graphics are they for?
Are they used for rendering raster and vector images?? Or what??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line drawing functions are generally used for *vector graphics*. Raster graphics would normally be done with a function such as `BitBlt`.

Answer (score 2):

GDI is an abstract interface to arbitrary graphics targets, including pixel and vector based displays. Versions of GDI were used to draw the entire interface in Windows prior to Windows Vista, and as a means by which to communicate to many printers.

You'd use the methods you mention to draw a vector line. It will be written as pixels if the device you're drawing to thinks in pixels.

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of most displays and graphic cards there is all graphics end up being raster graphics (setting a pixel to light up). [There are vector based displays and cards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_monitor)

From a program's perspective you need a way of deciding which pixels should be colored and how. A program might also want to manipulate the image.

The program's perspective might be raster or vector. [Each has its own advantages](http://www.graphicdesignforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=41).

The GDI APIs LineTo and MoveTo instruct the display to show a line or move the virtual cursor. Both methods could support a vector and a raster model because in the end they just color the pixels.